# Finding the value of $f(x)\times f(-x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble understanding the intuition needed to solve this problem. If  $f(0)=3$ and $f(x)\times f'(-x)=f(-x)\times f'(x)$ for all $ x $. Then how can we find the value of $f(x)\times f(-x)$.

Can someone please explain to me what the answer would be to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(f(x)f(-x))'=f'(x)f(-x)-f(x)f'(-x)=0\Rightarrow f(x)f(-x)=C$$
So $f(0)=3$ implies $C=9$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) \cdot f'(-x)=f(-x) \cdot f'(x) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{f'(-x)}{f(-x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \\ \Rightarrow -\ln f(-x)=\ln f(x)+c \\ \Rightarrow \ln f(-x)+\ln f(x) =C \\ \Rightarrow \ln (f(-x) \cdot f(x))=C \\ \Rightarrow f(-x) \cdot f(x)=M, \text{ where } M=e^C $$

We have that $f(0)=3$ so setting $x=0$ at the above relation we get $$f(0) \cdot f(0)=M \Rightarrow M=9$$

Therefore, $$f(-x) \cdot f(x)=9$$